# Calling child member from Base/Parent array?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, inheritance, arduino

So, I have a base class and a child class. Something like

```
Class Device 
{
     double read();
}

Class Relay : Public Device
{
      void toggleSwitch();
}

Class Sensor : Public Device
{
      int getValue();
}
```

I have an array to store the objects so I can keep track of them

```
Device *devices[10];
devices[0] = new Relay();
devices[1] = new Sensor();
etc…


devices[0]->toggleSwitch(); // error
```

I can call the member read() from any of these devices fine since read() is in the base class. So how do I call toggleSwitch() in Relay? I would get an error saying 'class Device' has no member named 'toggleSwith'. It makes sense since the 'devices' array is of Device. So how do I call a member of the child? I tried casting but it wasn't having it.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is that when you know device[i] is a pointer to Relay then just cast it.

```
((Relay *)devices[i])->toggleSwitch();
```

The disadvantage of virtual functions is the added overhead (more memory usage and slower code), but this can get problematic only if you allocate a really a big (millions) amount of instances of your class. You also need to modify the base class (if it's third part code you may don't want that).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use (pure) virtual functions. In your base class, add the following:

`virtual void toggleSwitch() = 0;`
`virtual int getValue() = 0;`

The above will now result in those virtual functions implemented in your specialisations being able to be called via your base class pointers.